# Error in Nextjs: Element type is invalid. How to fix this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building a Next.js app and I faced with this error:

> error - Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Here is my code:

```
"use client";
import { NextPage } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
import LoginForm from "../components/LoginForm";

import {
  Tabs,
  Form,
  Input,
  UserOutlined,
  LockOutlined,
  Checkbox,
  Button,
} from "antd";

function AuthPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <main style={{ width: 400, margin: "30px auto" }}>
        <Tabs
          defaultActiveKey="1"
          items={[
            {
              label: "Registration",
              key: "1",
              children: "Tab 1",
            },
            {
              label: "Login",
              key: "2",
              children: "Tab 2",
            },
          ]}
        />
        <LoginForm />
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default AuthPage;
```

Everything with `import/export` seems to be correct. I can not figure it out. Please help me

Here is my code in `LoginForm`:

```
import {
  Form,
  Input,
  UserOutlined,
  LockOutlined,
  Checkbox,
  Button,
} from "antd";

const LoginForm = () => (
  <div>
    <Form name="basic" labelCol={{ span: 8 }}>
      <Form.Item
        name="username"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your Username!" }]}
      >
        <Input
          prefix={<UserOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
          placeholder="Username"
        />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="password"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your Password!" }]}
      >
        <Input
          prefix={<LockOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Form.Item name="remember" valuePropName="checked" noStyle>
          <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>
        <a className="login-form-forgot" href="">
          Forgot password
        </a>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
          Log in
        </Button>
        Or <a href="">register now!</a>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  </div>
);

export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing your icons from the wrong package. You should be importing them from `@ant-design/icons` instead of from `antd`.

```js
import { UserOutlined, LockOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
```